# WordPress Dashboard Problem

Tags: themes, dashboard, customization

I am having difficulties changing my dashboard address. Currently it is pointed to my_domaincom.wordpress.com/wp-admin while it needs to be my_domain.com/wp-admin: with the current dashboard I cannot upload themes (see images below).

There is no "Add New" button.
[image: Current Dashboard]

Example of a dashboard (from a tutorial) that has the 'Add New' button.
[image: Expected Dashboard]4.jpg

Additional Info: My current plan is premium and I am using HostGator.
Any thoughts on how to change the dashboard?

Comment: please ask the WordPress.com support  https://en.support.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks, I understand now WordPress.com (not WordPress.org) is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you talk about WordPress.com or independent installation of WordPress.org on your server? These are two different things and your question confused because you mentioned that you have your own hosting also. For WordPress.com, contact their support. They should help you with this if you configured your domain there. If you installed WordPress.org independently on your server, I guess you used automatic installation that your hosting may provided. You can try to change the URL through database but best will be to contact your hosting company if you did it like that.

Comment: Yes, it's related to WordPress.com not an independent installation. Thanks for clarifying the distinction!